# UITextField Crash in Simulator not in iPhone 4 (4.2)

Tags: ios4, ios-simulator, uitextfield

I'm facing a strange issue and have no idea how to solve it.
I have in my app a simple viewcontroller with 3 textfield. I have define them as IBOutlet in my .h and linked them with the file's owner. 
Two of them are define with default Keyboard, the other use phone pad keyboard.
When i Try to edit the phone field (phone pad keyboard) it's ok. Keyboard appear, field can be modify.
When i try to edit one of the 2 others, then the app crash for the reason :"Terminating in response to SpringBoard's termination."

- I did not receive memory warning.
- This works fine if i try it on the iPhone 4 iOS 4.2 or iPhone Simulator 4.1.

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance.

BR,

Smazimute

Comment: I'm coming across an issue similar to, if not the same as this...

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer to this issue. Turn off auto correct on the iPhone Simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset iphone simulator content and settings then restart Xcode